# Show one of the two values in the template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a simple element:

```
<dom-module id="example-element">
  <template>
    <span>{{showAorB??}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polyemer({
    is: 'example-element',
    parameters: {
      a: String,
      b: String
    }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

I use it like this:

```
<example-element a="{{a}}" b="{{b}}">
```

In my scenario, one of `a` or `b` is always `undefined`.

What I'm confused about is **how to implement `{{showAorB}}` part**. Essentially what I want is something like `a || b`.

What I've tried:

- computed property / function (`{{showAorB(a,b)}}`) - doesn't work because it waits for both `a` and `b` to be `!== undefined` which, in my case, means it waits forever
- `<span hidden$='{{!a}}'>{{a}}</span><span hidden$='{{!b}}'>{{b}}</span>` - it's just awkward

What's the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function syntax (`{{showAorB(a,b)}}`) but in your `properties` declaration (you showed `parameters` but it should be `properties`) give `a` and `b` falsey (but not `undefined`) values. Like so:

```
properties: {
  a: {
    value: ''
  },
  b: {
    value: ''
  }
},
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/jazava/edit?html,output